# How to install Diablo 2 Lord of Destruction?

Tags: games, iso

I first tried to install Diablo 2 LOD from an iso image using acetone iso. However, after acetone iso mounted the image, it said "Please install the labelled disc".

I then tried with Gmount, and, following advice I received from some forums, I attempted to create mount points and then install; after it mounted the image, it installed the first three disc images but not the expansion.

When I tried to play, it told me to insert the labelled disc, even though the iso image was still mounted with Gmount. How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: I would suggest that you try using the .exe that you can download via Blizzard's website.

Comment: You can install PlayOnLinux. It's a manager for install games on Linux http://www.playonlinux.com/en

Comment: I do believe the latest-lastest patch for it disables the disk check

Answer (score 1):

In order to configure Diablo II to read the CD, you have to change Wine propierties (I assume that you are using Wine because it is impossible otherwise) and change the letter of the CD drive linking it to the iso mounted.

If not, use another .exe to run the program ;)

Comment: which letter should I use? I tried with D: but it didn't work

Comment: which properties should be changed? how do you access Wine properties? How do you change the letter of the cd drive to the iso mounted?

Answer (score 1):

Install PlayOnLinux and use that, It even comes with it's own wine bottle system, similar to Crossover. It makes it easy to edit the registry for better performance, and it even comes with nifty installation scripts. I also use furius iso mount, to mount my isos. It's in the USC.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've read about Diablo it's not designed to run on linux-based operating systems like Ubuntu, however, you can probably run it if a .exe or .msi file is available for its installation by use of wine.

Answer (score 0):

Open `winecfg`. Go to `Drives` tab, there you should map path of your mount point to correct drive (D:).

Answer (score 0):

According to [WineHQ](http://appdb.winehq.org/appview.php?iVersionId=315) you should be able to run it.

So you should install, open terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

Let the installer finish installing Wine.

And now you can insert the dialbo disk and run the .exe

And if you legally bought Diablo 2 LOD you should have a downloadable alternative on battle.net, which should not ask for a cd when installed.
And you could always download a crack, desperate times ask for desperate solutions.

> Wine folders:
>   Wine installation:
>   Wine will now install diablo 2 to it's "c" drive, which is located in
>   your home folder with the name ".wine". This folder is hidden by
>   default.
> Wine as a program:
>   
>  When users think of emulators, they think of programs like Dosbox or zsnes. These 
>   applications run as virtual machines and are slow, having to emulate
>   each processor instruction. Wine does not do any CPU emulation - hence
>   the name "Wine Is Not an Emulator." Some people argue that since Wine
>   introduces an extra layer above the system a Windows application will
>   run slowly. While technically true, Wine is no different from any
>   other software library in this regard; even newer versions of Windows
>   must load extra resources to support older applications.
>   
>  [source](http://wiki.winehq.org/Debunking_Wine_Myths#head-7c9ecddfaff60d8891414b68d74277244e7109eb)

Comment: just updated the text