# Launch Diablo 2 Lord of Destruction with Wine from CD

Tags: 13.10, wine

1. I installed Diablo II Lord of Destruction with Wine on my Ubuntu 13.10.
2. I mounted .iso file.
3. I opened "Drives" settings in "Configure wine" and changed mounted disc to drive `D:`. (In my case `/media/milkovsky/Diablo II LOD)`.
4. Whed I try to launch `DiabloII.exe` I alvays get popup message `Please verify that your Diablo 2 Expansion Disc is in your CD-OM drive, than click 'Retry'`.

**P.S.** You may think this question could be duplicate of [How to install Diablo 2 Lord of Destruction?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/204374/how-to-install-diablo-2-lord-of-destruction) but I didn't find a solution for me there. I tried all the anserws

Comment: Have you tried using PlayOnLinux? Maybe it's setup script will fix this for you

Comment: I could try. Could you please tell how can I install Diablo using .iso in Play on Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Step 4' is wrong. You just need to do this instead

```
 # wine cmd.exe
 # d:\
 # d:\install
```

and you can proceed : )